# Derive Dataframe having uncommon rows based on a single column of another Dataframe

Tags: dataframe, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

I have encountered an issue where in I have to get uncommon rows from a dataframe based on a column of another dataframe.
Example being
First dataframe i.e df1

| _id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 12 | abc |
| 56 | def |
| 90 | jkl |

reference Dataframe i.e df2 :-

| _id | user_name | event_name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | abc | some |
| 34 | xyz | left |
| 56 | def | right |
| 78 | ghi | middle |
| 90 | jkl | front |

The third dataframe is expected to have

| _id | user_name | event_name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 34 | xyz | left |
| 78 | ghi | middle |

To achieve this I have tried two approach :-

Approach 1
Getting the list of id's from df2 and using isin to filter the columns using below

```
val idsList = df1.select("_id").dropDuplicates().map(_.getInt(0)).collect.toList
val dffDf = df2.filter(not($"_id".isin(idsList: _*)))
```

The problem with this approach is the **collect** function is too heavy and it takes lot of time as all calculation happens at driver level.

Approach 2
Using left anti join

```
 df2.join(df1, df2("_id") ===  df1("_id"),"leftanti")
```

But this is giving me below issue

```
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.errors.package$TreeNodeException: Max iterations (100) reached for batch Resolution, please set 'spark.sql.analyzer.maxIterations' to a larger value
```

The issue is mentioned in https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-37222 without any solution.

Is there any other recommendation for achieving this ??
Any pointer will be great. I would need a solution which is effective as well as is not heavy or time consuming.
Using spark 3.3.0 version.

Comment: Isn't this just an outer join and then keeping only rows where df1 is null?

Comment: @GaëlJ no that will not help as that means it will have all the columns of both df combined. I think the question may be confusing because of column name. I have edited the question a bit to give much clarity.

Comment: You can select the columns you need if that's the only issue. I still don't see why a simple outer join wouldn't work.

Comment: `left_anti` I think is the right way to go. I tried the same code and it worked fine for me in spark 3.3.0. Can you please share the rest of the code after this join? `input2.join(input1, input2("_id") === input1("_id"), "left_anti")`

Answer (score 0):

Here are two of the many ways you can solve this -

**Using left_anti**

```
    import spark.implicits._

val input1 = Seq(
  (12, "abc"),
  (56, "def"),
  (90, "jkl")
).toDF("_id", "name")

val input2 = Seq(
  (12, "abc", "some"),
  (34, "xyz", "left"),
  (56, "def", "right"),
  (78, "ghi", "middle"),
  (90, "jkl", "front")
).toDF("_id", "username", "event_name")
println("spark.version : " + spark.version)

val finalDf = input2.join(input1, input2("_id") === input1("_id"), "left_anti")

println("result : ")
finalDf.show

/*
spark.version : 3.3.0
result : 
+---+--------+----------+
|_id|username|event_name|
+---+--------+----------+
| 34|     xyz|      left|
| 78|     ghi|    middle|
+---+--------+----------+
 */
```

**Using left_outer**

```
    import spark.implicits._
val input1 = Seq(
  (12, "abc"),
  (56, "def"),
  (90, "jkl")
).toDF("_id", "name")

val input2 = Seq(
  (12, "abc", "some"),
  (34, "xyz", "left"),
  (56, "def", "right"),
  (78, "ghi", "middle"),
  (90, "jkl", "front")
).toDF("_id", "username", "event_name")

println("spark.version : " + spark.version)

val finalDf = input2.as("input2").join(input1.as("input1"), input2("_id") === input1("_id"), "left_outer").where(input1("_id").isNull)
println("result : ")
finalDf.select("input2.*").show


/*
spark.version : 3.3.0
result :
+---+--------+----------+
|_id|username|event_name|
+---+--------+----------+
| 34|     xyz|      left|
| 78|     ghi|    middle|
+---+--------+----------+

 */
```